# Как увеличить размер ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

У меня `ListView` с секциями. И когда секция появляется, то она становится на место другого. То есть если размер `ListView` 30, то секция становится на место первого пункта, и получается так что показываются только 29 пунктов.

Вот картинка, где показано четко

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробовал `TYPE_MAX_COUNT = 2, 3`. Без толку.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
}
```

Такое чувство, что `getViewTypeCount()` срабатывает после `getView()`.

Вот сам адаптер:

```
private List<VacancyModel> vacancyModelList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private SQLHelper sqlHelper;

private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
private int rowType;

public static String saveLastDate;
private int newRecs = 0;

public SuitableAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<VacancyModel> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vacancyModelList = objects;

    sqlHelper = new SQLHelper(getContext());

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    rowType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        switch (rowType) {
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suitable_separator_layout, null);
                holder.headerTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.section_header);

                break;

            case TYPE_ITEM:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
                holder.tvProfession = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvProfession);
                holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
                holder.tvSalary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSalary);
                holder.tvDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPostCr);
                break;
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_SEPARATOR) {

        holder.headerTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.section_header);

        if (newRecs == 1) {
            holder.headerTv.setText("Новые вакансии");
            newRecs = 0;
        } else {
            holder.headerTv.setText("Ранее просмотренные");
        }
    }

    if (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_ITEM) {

        final VacancyModel model = vacancyModelList.get(position);

        holder.tvProfession.setText(model.getProfession());
        holder.tvHeader.setText(model.getHeader());
        holder.tvSalary.setText(model.getSalary());
        holder.tvDate.setText(model.getDate());

        Date date;
        try {
            if (saveLastDate == null) {
                saveLastDate = model.getDate();
            } else {
                date = stringToDate(saveLastDate);
                if (date.before(stringToDate(model.getDate()))) {
                    saveLastDate = model.getDate();
                }
            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (GlobalData.LoadDate(getContext()) == null) {
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    } else {
        VacancyModel model = getItem(position);

        if (model != null) {
            String newString = model.getDate();
            String lastString = GlobalData.LoadDate(getContext());

            Date newDate = null;
            Date lastDate = null;

            try {
                newDate = stringToDate(newString);
                lastDate = stringToDate(lastString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            assert newDate != null;

            if (newDate.equals(lastDate)) {
                return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
            } else if (position == 0 && newDate.after(lastDate)) {
                newRecs = 1;
                return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
            } else {
                return TYPE_ITEM;
            }
        } else {
            return TYPE_ITEM;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return vacancyModelList.size();
}

private Date stringToDate(String string) throws ParseException {
    return new SimpleDateFormat(("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), Locale.getDefault()).parse(string);
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvProfession;
    private TextView tvHeader;
    private TextView tvSalary;
    private TextView tvDate;

    private TextView headerTv;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы отображать разделитель как отдельный элемент нужна довольно сложная логика. Тогда есть 3 варианта:

1. Отображать разделитель как часть обычного элемента. Т.е. в suitable_separator_layout добавить вью из row_layout и в getView, когда rowType == TYPE_SEPARATOR, нужно заполнять tvProfession, tvSalary и т.д.
2. Использовать [библиотеку](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)
3. Отнаследоваться от BaseAdapter, по тому как вы используете некоторые методы не вдаваясь в детали что собственно это за методы и что они делают. Например `getItem(position)`. При создании адаптера сразу определить где будут находиться разделители и при получении модели для отображения нужно:

   final VacancyModel model = vacancyModelList.get(position - separatorsCount);

Где `separatorsCount` нужно вычислить исходя из того где у вас находятся разделители относительно текущего элемента Т.е. если у вас разделитель на position 0 и 3, то для того что бы отобразить элемент в position == 4, нужно взять из списка модель с индексом 2, а не 4.

И еще:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return vacancyModelList.size() + 2;
}
```

Так как у вас всегда 2 разделителя.